# Way to get all xml element ids and count into one number?

Tags: php, xml

Ok so lets say i have an xml what looks like this example,

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

   <stats id="865" name="blaah">
       <example name="blaahblaah">
           <example1>
               <x ppoints="500"/>
           </example1>
           <example2>
               <x ppoints ="150"/>
               <x points ="500"/>
               <x ppoints ="140"/>
               <x points="200"/>
           </example2>
       </example>
   </stats>
```

what i am trying to do here is to get all the ppoints and round them into one number and all the points and round them into one number,
like so

Stats: "rounded up ppoints" pp & "rounded up points" p

help anyone? many thanks

Comment: And what do you have so far? Haven't you even loaded the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, as I understand the structure of the document can contain multiple 'example' nodes, I think the best approach is to load the XML document and use a XPath expression to get all the nodes with a `ppoints` attribute and a `points` attribute.

Using XPath there are two possible solutions. One using [SimpleXMLElement::xpath](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) to retrieve all the required nodes and sum them manually. And another one using [DOMXPath::evaluate](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domxpath.evaluate.php) which allows to evaluate any type of XPath expression and sum the values just using XPath. The latter solutions is simpler.

*DOMXPath::evaluate*

```
<?php

$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->load('file.xml');
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

$sum_ppoints = $xpath->evaluate('sum(//x/@ppoints)');
$sum_points = $xpath->evaluate('sum(//x/@points)');

print "Ppoints: $sum_ppoints; Points: $sum_points\n";

?>
```

*SimpleXMLElement::xpath*

```
<?php

// Load XML file
$file = "file.xml";
$content = file_get_contents($file);
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($content);

// Compute sum ppoints
$sum_ppoints = 0;
$nodes = $xml->xpath('//x[@ppoints]');
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    $sum_ppoints += $node->attributes()->ppoints;
}

// Compute sum points
$sum_points = 0;
$nodes = $xml->xpath('//x[@points]');
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    $sum_points += $node->attributes()->points;
}

print "Ppoints: $sum_ppoints; Points: $sum_points\n";

?>
```

Comment: I am not a php expert but if you can use XPath why not just `sum(//x/@points)` and `sum(//x/@ppoints)` ?

Comment: @Pawel Thanks for the pointer. I didn't know about sum. According to the PHP docs SimpleXMLElement::xpath "searches the SimpleXML node for children matching the XPath path", so apparently is only useful for searching nodes. I tried the expression and it fails. However, there's another PHP function DOMXPath::evaluate that "Executes the given XPath expression and returns a typed result if possible". With this function it works. Updated answer.